# increase image's width until its original one, inside a responsive DIV container

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a `<div>` container which takes 80% of the screen (responsive page).
Inside this `<div>` I want to display an image which is 400 x 400 (pixels).

**My goal:**

1. The screen width increases: The `<div>`'s width will increase. The image's width will increase at maximum to 400px.
2. The screen width decreases: The `<div>`'s width will decrease. The image's width will start to decrease when the screen's width is less than 400px.

This is my [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vigacowise/edit?html,css,output).

Any idea?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nixisacoye/1/edit?html,css,output see this

Comment: Try this out. http://jsbin.com/zoneqipufa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: All the answers and comments are correct. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set heigth and width to 100% on your img:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src= "https://s14.postimg.org/4nu4hmvyp/8222.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 400px;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the img to take up 100% of the width of it's parent with `width: 100%`. The `max-width` will then prevent it expanding over 400px:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src= "https://s14.postimg.org/4nu4hmvyp/8222.jpg">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one(IE6 support):

```
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: expression(this.offsetWidth > 400 ? "400px" : "auto");
}
```